# difficulties to use php file for a custom css in drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-7, hook

i would like to use a custom css for a specific page. In order to perform this objective, i have implemented hook_menu and hook_theme.
I have a link with a php file

```
$url = drupal_get_path('module', 'preview_ipad') . '/css/style-css.php';
drupal_add_css($url);
```

In this php file, there is custom css :

```
<?php
    header('content_type : text/css');
?>

* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body {
    background: url(./ret/white.png) no-repeat 50% top;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    color: <?php echo $_SESSION['color'] ?>;
}
```

The link exist, in the source code of my page, but there is a problem. The css doesn't work.

help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the CSS file loads last. Because by default drupal loads the theme's CSS files after the module's CSS files.

Try to make the following changes to this code:

```
$url = drupal_get_path('module', 'preview_ipad') . '/css/style-css.php';
drupal_add_css($url, array(
    'group' => CSS_THEME,
    'weight' => 1000,
));
```

Comment: also you can provide $_GET[] variable, maybe that is easier for some session issues